# Virtual/mock external monitor drivers for Windows to test multiple displays?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display-driver, winapi

I am authoring a software that should work properly when a Windows environment has multiple displays attached to it.

Sadly, I only have a single monitor attached to my PC so I cannot easily test the software I am authoring.

Are there recommendations that would allow creating such virtual monitor devices and let me have multiple displays on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

Additional Windows displays (up to 4) can be easily create using the [**Spacedesk**](https://www.spacedesk.net/) app.

Your Android/Apple smartphone, tablet or Windows 7/10 PC will be a real extended Windows displays. All regular functions for testing your app will work, including Windows Extended Desktop.

Comment: I’m not sure if you’ve correctly understood my question. I don’t want to use external devices as displays.

Comment: There are no ways to get a pure virtual display under Windows.
WDDM Source-Target model does not allow you to do this without setting *Target.*

As a temporary option for testing applications, Spacedesk will be the easiest way. 
Phone or Tablet  to organize *Target* is always there.
You can check all Windows multi-display options (Win-P), including Windows Extended Desktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2022, it’s now possible with the new [Microsoft Indirect Display Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/indirect-display-driver-model-overview) API, there are already a [few tutorials](https://archeb.medium.com/how-to-run-parsec-without-monitor-heres-a-virtual-monitor-solution-for-you-indirect-display-ecba5173b86a) and an [open-source implementation](https://github.com/ge9/IddSampleDriver). There are also closed-source (but free) implementations such as [Amyuni’s](https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3030).